# Read arbitrary number of input stdin

Tags: go

I need to read arbitrary number of inputs from `stdin`. I have following code which is working fine and reads arbitrary number of input from command-line:

```
// Reads from command-line arguments
package main

import(
        "fmt"
        "os"
        "strconv"
)

func main(){
        for _,arg := range os.Args[1:] {
                n, err := strconv.Atoi(arg)
                if err != nil {
                        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Error: %v\n", err)
                        os.Exit(1)
                }
                fmt.Printf("%d\n", n)
        }
}
```

But, I want to change it to read from `stdin`, and what I have done is following:

```
// Reads input from stdin
package main

import "fmt"

func main(){
        var a, b, c, d int
        count, err := fmt.Scan(&a, &b, &c, &d)
        fmt.Printf("Arguments Read: %d\n", count)
        fmt.Printf("%d, %d, %d, %d\n", a, b, c, d)
        if err != nil {
                fmt.Printf("%v\n", err)
        }
}
```

But in the second version of code I am bound to read fixed number of arguments from `stdin`. How can I read arbitrary number of arguments from `stdin`?

Comment: You can loop over `fmt.Scan()` until you get the number of arguments you want.

Comment: As `fmt.Scan()` returns `(n int, err error)`. What would be the condition to loop on?

Comment: You loop over the amount of arguments you want to get or until you receive specific argument.

Comment: The number of arguments are not fixed beforehand, as my program reads arbitrary number of arguments, as evident from first code block.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over condition and keep on reading input from stdin until that condition is satisfied. In below example if input is "exit" program finishes reading and outputs all provided arguments.

```
inputOpen := true
var args []string

fmt.Println("Provide argument, type exit to finish")
for inputOpen {
    var arg string
    var err error

    if _, err = fmt.Scan(&arg); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("%v\n", err)
    }


    if arg == "exit" {
        inputOpen = false
    } else {
        args = append(args, arg)
    }
}

fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("Arguments: %v", args))
```